# Doctrine doesn't link to associations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to add entries to a MySQL database by using a REST endpoint in a Symfony 3.1 app (and PHP 7.1).

I have two entities: Role and Permission, in a many to many relationship.

```
/**
 * Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DruideBundle\Entity\Repository\RoleRepository")
 *
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $titre = '';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_role", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idRole;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @Type("array<DruideBundle\Entity\Permission>")
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="DruideBundle\Entity\Permission", mappedBy="idRole", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $idPermission;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitre() {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $titre
     */
    public function metsTitre($titre) {
        $this->titre = $titre;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $titre
     */
    public function setTitre($titre) {
        $this->titre = $titre;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->idRole;
    }

    public function addIdPermission($permission) {
        $this->idPermission->add($permission);
    }

    public function removeIdPermission($permission) {
        $this->idPermission->remove($permission);
    }

    public function setIdPermission($permission) {
        $this->idPermission = $permission;
    }

    public function getIdPermission() {
        return $this->idPermission;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->idPermission = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

}

/**
 * Permission
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="permission", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="valeur", columns={"cle"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DruideBundle\Entity\Repository\PermissionRepository")
 */
class Permission
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cle", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cle;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCle() {
        return $this->cle;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cle
     */
    public function metsCle($cle) {
        $this->cle = $cle;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cle
     */
    public function setCle($cle) {
        $this->cle = $cle;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function metsDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->idPermission;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_permission", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idPermission;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="DruideBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="idPermission")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_permission",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_permission", referencedColumnName="id_permission")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_role", referencedColumnName="id_role")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $idRole;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->idRole = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

}

class RoleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('titre', TextType::class)->
                    add('idPermission', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => PermissionType::class));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DruideBundle\Entity\Role', 'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'druidebundle_role';
    }

}

class RoleController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{
    public function postAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(RoleType::class, null, [
            'csrf_protection' => false,        
        ]);

        $form->submit($request->request->all());

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return View::create($form->getErrors(true), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        /**
         * @var $role Role
         */
        $role = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($role);
        $em->flush();

        $routeOptions = [
            'id' => $role->getId(),
            '_format' => $request->get('_format'),
        ];

        $reponse = $this->routeRedirectView('get_roles', $routeOptions, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
        return $this->handleView($reponse);
    }
```

Now, if I send this JSON to create a new role:

```
{ "titre": "Test Pascal", "permissions": [ { "id": 1 }, { "id": 3 } ] }
```

I would expect it to create a new Role, and make links to the two existing permissions. Sadly, Doctrine is only creating the Role entity:

```
[2017-12-04 21:02:08] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2017-12-04 21:02:08] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO role (titre) VALUES (?) {"1":"Test Pascal"} []
[2017-12-04 21:02:08] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
```

What is missing?

Comment: No need to `persist` object existing in repository,

Comment: if you change @Type("array to @Type("ArrayCollection does that change anything?

Comment: @MEmerson, changing it to ArrayCollection have the same behavior.

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski: the role object is new, so I do need to persist this one.